# jQuery - How to format HTML content to remove tags but insert \n

Tags: jquery, regex, formatting, tinymce

I am trying to format HTML contents in jQuery for posting to a Facebook event.

Essentially I want to take a block of content like:

```
<p>Plus&nbsp;<a id=\"js_131\" href=\"https://www.facebook.com/themotorleague?directed_target_id=0\" data-hovercard=\"/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=42475533139&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A0%7D\" data-mce-href=\"https://www.facebook.com/themotorleague?directed_target_id=0\">The Motorleague</a></p>
<p><a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/AtomiqueProductions/events?directed_target_id=0\" data-hovercard=\"/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=133649633385384&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A0%7D\" data-mce-href=\"https://www.facebook.com/AtomiqueProductions/events?directed_target_id=0\">Atomique Productions</a>&nbsp;and&nbsp;<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/thezone.fm?directed_target_id=0\" data-hovercard=\"/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=339763011997&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A0%7D\" data-mce-href=\"https://www.facebook.com/thezone.fm?directed_target_id=0\">The Zone @ 91-3, Modern Rock in Victoria</a>&nbsp;present</p>
<p>-&nbsp;<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/TheBalconies?directed_target_id=0\" data-hovercard=\"/ajax/hovercard/page.php?id=7677069042&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22directed_target_id%22%3A0%7D\" data-mce-href=\"https://www.facebook.com/TheBalconies?directed_target_id=0\">THE BALCONIES</a>&nbsp;-</p>
```

And pass it through a jQuery function to remove all HTML tags, **but** wherever a `<p>` is present, add `\n\r\` to make it look like:

> Plus The Motorleague
>
> Atomique Productions and The Zone @ 91-3, Modern Rock in Victoria
>   present
>
> - THE BALCONIES -

Is this possible?

*If it's relevant, the HTML content is coming directly from a WordPress post page's TinyMCE editor.*

Comment: All I've been able to do is assign the content to a JS `var`; as I have no idea how to do this I was hoping for a little guidance

Comment: I would imagine it would be some form of `str.replace` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you mean:

```
var $el = jQuery('p');

console.log(doit($el));

function doit($el)
{
  var ret = '';
  $el.each(function()
  {
      ret += jQuery(this).text() + '\n\r';
  })
  return ret;
}
```

outputs:

```
Plus The Motorleague
Atomique Productions and The Zone @ 91-3, Modern Rock in Victoria present
- THE BALCONIES -
```

REVISIED:

```
var $el = jQuery('<div>' + str + '</div>').find('*');

console.log(doit($el));

function doit($el)
{
  var ret = '';
  $el.each(function()
  {
      var nl = $(this).is('p') ? '\n\r' : '';
      ret += jQuery(this).text() + nl;
  });
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Where in the function do I input my string?